# "Being generally discouraged"

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-request, sentence-choice

> The following approach, though being generally discouraged, is acceptable and may be useful in some rare cases.

I'm not sure this sentence is correct; the part that confuses me is **though being generally discouraged**. It confuses me because it seems nobody use it (according to Google), and this is strange, of course.

I can change it to **though it's generally discouraged**, which seems to be grammatically correct, but that way the sentence looks awkward to me.

Comment: The word ***being*** is both clumsy and completely unnecessary. Just remove it. You don't need to "replace" it with ***it's*** either (including that isn't *quite* so clunky, but the text flows better without it). On the "style" front, I'd suggest resequencing the "punch line" to something more like *The following approach is acceptable and may be useful in some rare cases, **but is generally discouraged***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The following approach, though being generally discouraged, is acceptable and may be useful in some rare cases.

The original example, after having its 'being' removed, is fine.  It stresses on the positive and that it is still acceptable.

@FumbleFingersReinstateMonica is right that we can re-sequence as commented.

The re-sequenced sentence has a slightly different feel and stresses on that it is discouraged.

To keep close to the original intended meaning, I suggest the following:

'The following approach is acceptable and may be useful in some rare cases 'though' it is generally discouraged.'